# Android Custom list loads very slow

Tags: android, listview, android-emulator

Made a custom list view that includes an Image, two text views and a checkbox. I could    identify the checkbox being checked/ unchecked, but the problem with this design is very slow scrolling. Will this get faster if I test it into the real device.

```
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<Model> compositeAdapter = new CompositeAdapter(this,
            getModel());
    setListAdapter(compositeAdapter);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
   }
}

private class CompositeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public CompositeAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.listviewactivitylayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView textView1;
        protected TextView textView2;
        protected ImageView imageView;
        protected CheckBox ckBox;
    }
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        final ViewHolder vh;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater li = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.listviewactivitylayout, null);
             vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.ckBox =(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_layout_checkbox);
            vh.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_image_view);
            vh.textView1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_layout_text_view1);
            vh.textView2= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_text_view2);
            view.setTag(vh);
        }
        else{
            view= convertView;
            vh = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

/**
** sending text and images to the each of the list view
**
*/
```

Comment: are you testing this in the emulator or on a phone? The emulator tends to be incredibly slow from my experience, so if you are using the emulator there might not be anything wrong with your code at all.

Comment: Post your code. Without it, it's hard to say what's wrong..

Comment: @redEvo -> true. Emulator speed is pain in the ...^H^H^H neck

Comment: I have used the local images so is it better to load the image ti the list view in thread/async task or simply general loading mechanism(as in the code above) works fine ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading images. that needs to be handled in a seperate thread and just placed on an imageView when it is decoded.

here is a excelent project that will help you do that.
[Lazy load images](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

**EDIT**

by looking at your code there are few things i am noticing:

**First:** there isnt any place you are asigning a picture. (use the lazy loading adapter for that)

**Second:** your checkbox selections will get messed up. you need to keep track of the checked position with state and redraw in getView (hashmap or even better a sparse array for that)

**Third** is to get rid of the helper view you are using. you don't need it. (it is market as `View view` in your code).

So, if `convertView==null` just use `convertView=inflate...` and return that one at the end.

And **Fourth** as a useful tip: move the adapter class to a new class java file. you are already keeping the activity reference and the list, you can reduce the amount of code in your activity.